# Highcharts custom doughnut graph

Tags: highcharts

[image]

Does anyone have any idea how to make a graph like this? It's basically 5 in one chart, each one represents a different dynamic value up to 100%. So like the man running icon would be 60%, scale 85%, sleep 8%, ect.

The icons in the middle obviously won't be part of the graph, they'd be a div overlayed the chart.

Can anyone help? If highcharts will not work, then what will?

Comment: What functionality do you need? If you only care about the dynamic values being "alive" then you can just make a standard doughnut chart with highcharts and overlay your icons and those grayed out chunks under the chart

Comment: What you have, have you any code with missing elements, like icons ?